# How to have both MasterDetailPage & TabbedPages in Xamarin.iOS App?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

How to have both MasterDetailPage & TabbedPages in Xamarin.iOS App?

Our requirement is to have Account Setting in the MasterDetailPage and have TabbedPages for Page level Tabs.

How to integrate both MasterDetailPage and TabbedPages in Xamarin iOS App ?

Comment: Can't you just set a TabbedPage as the Detail for a MasterDetailPage?

Comment: @valdetero, I wanted to do only as TabbedPage .. but the requirement insisting us to have MasterDetailPage along with Tabbedpage.

Comment: brandon did exactly what I was suggesting.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a sample that shows how to add a `TabbedPage` as a `Detail` page inside of a `MasterDetailPage`.

The official Xamarin docs go into more detail about implementing a `MasterDetailPage`:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/master-detail-page/

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SampleApp
{
    public class SamplePage : ContentPage
    {
        public SamplePage(string title)
        {
            Title = title;

            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Children = {
                    new Label
                    {
                        Text = title
                    }
                }
            };

        }
    }

    public class MasterPageItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string IconSource { get; set; }

        public Type TargetType { get; set; }
    }

    public class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            var tabbedPage = new TabbedPage
            {
                Children = {
                    new SamplePage("Page 1"),
                    new SamplePage("Page 2"),
                    new SamplePage("Page 3")
                }
            };

            var masterPageItems = new List<MasterPageItem>();
            masterPageItems.Add(new MasterPageItem
            {
                Title = "Detail Page",
                IconSource = "icon",
                TargetType = typeof(SamplePage)
            });

            var masterListView = new ListView
            {
                ItemsSource = masterPageItems,
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
                {
                    var imageCell = new ImageCell();
                    imageCell.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "Title");
                    imageCell.SetBinding(ImageCell.ImageSourceProperty, "IconSource");
                    return imageCell;
                }),
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None
            };

            var masterDetailPage = new MasterDetailPage
            {
                Detail = new NavigationPage(tabbedPage),
                Master = new ContentPage
                {
                    Content = masterListView,
                    Title = "=",
                    Padding = new Thickness(0, Device.OnPlatform(20, 0, 0), 0, 0)
                }
            };

            MainPage = masterDetailPage;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you .. i will have to try implementing your code logic..!!

Comment: You're welcome; glad to help! If you don't have any follow up questions, let's mark this question as Answered to help fellow developers in the future when they have a similar question!

Comment: Hi goofyui! Were you successful implementing this solution?

Comment: I haven't yet. I will have to finish up this task by this week end. For now, my settings page is in the Tabbed Page. I really want to reach you out, but dont know .. how to get in touch..

Comment: @goofyui you can find me on Twitter, @ BrandonXamarin